# Smart counter around kitchen sink

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, stone, kitchen-sink, marble

I am replacing my kitchen, and I'm going to use bamboo for the kitchen top. Imagine the rough layout where T = Top, W = Wall, S = Sink, R = Refrigerator.

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTSSSSSSW
                              SSSSSSW
                              SSSSSSW
                              RRRRRRW
                              RRRRRRW
```

Because of the extra wall in the corner, the sink area can't use the same continuous material as the kitchen top. And besides, since it's a wet area, wood is not the ideal material anyway.

I thought some stone like marble would be nice, but 80% of the material will be cut away to make the hole for the sink, so you're basically paying five times what you end up using.

Thus I'm wondering if there's a smart and cheaper way out of this predicament. Is there a nice-looking, water resistant material suitable that doesn't involve a lot of wasted investment?

Comment: They make sinks that have their own porcelain surrounds; perhaps you can find one that works in your (unusual) situation.

Comment: I think you should seriously rethink your layout. Pushing the sink half way past the return from the long side will make the sink a total pain to use. I would take a hard look at corner type sinks.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: There is a wall in the corner, so the sink can't be there. Maybe the figure is misleading; I'll try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Shop for a stainless steel sink with integrated drainboard. Some designs even have an apron front to eliminate the strip of countertop in front of the sink.

If you can find a suitable one in the right size, you can make the countertop out of strips and the drainboard will cover the joins. The strips should be synthetic lumber such as polyurethane or High-density polyethylene, containing no biodegradable material.